# can't change radio button value by code - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a radio button, that when the user click "active" - an alert will appear. If he clicked cancel, stay (or go back) to the old value.
problem is, the what happens is that both of the radio buttons are "unchecked". and thats obviously not the wanted behaviour.

I've attached a code example.
[code example](http://jsbin.com/veneropuha/1/edit?html,js,output)

thanks in advance,
ben.

Comment: For me the inactive radio button is checked, maybe a browser issue? Try in chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add timeout before setting the value to false.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope,$timeout){

 $scope.value = {
   text : false
 };
  $scope.checkRadioButton = function() {
    if ($scope.value.text === true) {
      if (!window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.value.text =  false;
        });

      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you Avnesh,
would you mind explaining why this is the solution?

Comment: Ben David, The return value of calling $timeout is a promise, which will be resolved when the delay has passed and the timeout function, if provided, is executed.


Another solution by using $scope.$apply();


if ($scope.value.text === true) {
      if (!window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.value.text =  false;
      }
    }